# How to add a second language (ex Portuguese) on SilverStripe

Tags: installation, silverstripe

Is there a definitive guide to adding a second language (ex Portuguese) to a SilverStripe website? 
If not, I have made a start on it - see here: http://217.198.108.87/hham/wordpress/?page_id=61
however I cannot see what to do once I have successfully installed the extension!

Any suggestions welcome - and I shall append them to my installation instructions.
Tim

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure where you're stuck.

If you add `Object::add_extension('SiteTree', 'Translatable')` in your _config.php, then DONT also add the `$extensions` line to your Page class.

Page inherits from SiteTree.

If you look at the demo site  (http://demo.silverstripe.org/admin) you should see that each page when you edit it should have a Translations tab.

I assume you're not getting this?

Please provide some more information about the problem and lets see if we can sort it out.

Also, try this guide?
 http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2011/using-translatable-to-create-a-simple-multilingual-site

Sometimes the SilverStripe forum is more responsive than StackOverflow, as the core SStr team may see your question more quickly.